# Hide a div containing a broken image

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm working on a blog/website with an image carousel with 8 spots for images. I'm using Owl Carousel with CouchCMS (this shouldn't matter too much)..

Here's what the carousel looks like:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show blog_image />" class="carousel_image"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_2 />"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_3 />"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_4 />"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_5 />"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_6 />"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_7 />"></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="<cms:show image_8 />"></div>
</div>
```

Right now I have it so you can upload a max of 8 images using CouchCMS.

If you upload fewer than 8 images, the remaining are just shown as broken images.

Right now I'm using the following code to just hide the broken images, which of course leaves a blank div (which is still better than showing a broken image, though)... This is the best solution I could come up with.

```
$("img").error(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Does anyone know any way I could detect if an image is broken, and hide the entire div that contains the image?

Thanks.

**Below is an example of what I tried, but it didn't work.**

html

```
<div class="item" id="img-8-div"><img src="<cms:show image_8 />"></div>
```

And here's the JQuery, again it didnt work.

```
$("#img-8-div").children('img').error(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Did you tried 

`$(function(){if($("#img-8-div").children().attr("src") == ""){  $("#img-8-div").hide();}
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73zez/1/)

Use jQuery **[parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**

```
$("img").error(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: Do you ever have any one of those moments where you just can't think of things you should be able to? I just had one of those! Thanks!

Comment: Happens many times! There stackoverflow/ google come to the rescue.